# Error trying to run a WHILE loop within a subroutine

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will allow the user to input a numerical list that will be sorted through either Bubble, quick, insertion or merge sort depending on the user's selection.

I am testing the selection of bubble sort however I have problems. The variable numbers will not print, when taken out of the subroutine to be printed the contents are the same inputted list.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix it so that the bubble sort will run normally when used as a subroutine? FYI: the version of python is 3.6.2 and the bubble sort will work when not in a subroutine.

```
def bubble(numbers):
    import time 
    start = time.time()
    numItems = len(numbers)
    for i in range (0, numItems - 2):
        for j in range (0, numItems - i - 2):
            if numbers [j] > numbers [j + 1]:
                temp = numbers[j]
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1]
                numbers[j + 1] = temp
        print (numbers)
    end = time.time()
    print (end - start)

print ("Bubble, merge, quick and insertion sort visulizer.")
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Input your list ").split()]
bubble(numbers)
```

Comment: Please, post code as text no image of text

Comment: I've edited it twice to add in the code, I mistyped on the first edit.

Comment: Works for me. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: The output for my code is only the (end-start) timer which is 0.0. My intention was it would output the sorted list.

Comment: You're never printing the sorted list...

Comment: It should. When I run the bubble sort on its own the result is a run by run of each swap with the final output beign a sorted list and the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your `bubble` function `return` the resulting `numbers` list so that your main program can print it. Note that for bubble sort implementation is wrong, as it should have an upper bound that covers all the items:

```
def bubble(numbers):
    import time 
    start = time.time()
    numItems = len(numbers)
    for i in range (0, numItems):
        for j in range (0, numItems - i - 1):
            if numbers [j] > numbers [j + 1]:
                temp = numbers[j]
                numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1]
                numbers[j + 1] = temp
    end = time.time()
    print (end - start)
    return numbers

print ("Bubble, merge, quick and insertion sort visulizer.")
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Input your list ").split()]
numbers = bubble(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Tested this now, the program will just print the list input.

Comment: And what's your input?

Comment: By the way, although this is what you asked about, your implementation of bubble sort is wrong. I've updated my answer to correct the upper bounds in your implementation.

Comment: Unless I have messed up somewhere, the code you gave me still outputs the unsorted list.

Comment: My input is 495722

Comment: You definitely have. It prints sorted numbers just fine in my testing.

Comment: Your input should consist of a number of space-delimited numbers, such as `2 8 4 9 5 6`. Your input of `495722` is only one number and would not sort for sure because it does not need to be sorted.

Comment: Thank you!, just tested this my self and you were right. Thank you for the help.